# PHP DOMDocument createTextNode with namespace

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, google-shopping

I'm making an xml document for google shopping and had trouble with the encoding of the products description. I've tried different approaches with `str_replace` and escaping some characters, `utf8_encode`, `iconv` and some custom functions, but all generated encoding errors. Then I found someone who used `createTextNode` and that seemed to work for me, I got no errors.

The only problem I've got now is that I can't get the `createTextNode` in the right namespace (I hope I'm saying that the right way).

This is the code that worked, but failed on some product description due to encoding issues:

```
$addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['atom'], 'description', 'test content'));
```

This creates the right line:

```
<description>test content</description>
```

Now I want to use the `createTextNode` code, but can't get it working with the right tags. This works:

```
$addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createTextNode('test content'));
```

But this just puts the content in my main entry, while it needs to be between the description tags.

How can I put it in the description tags?
Or if you know a good way to solve the encoding issues while using my old code, that's fine too.

---

Here is the entire code I'm using:

```
function function_xml_entities($text = null, $charset = 'ISO-8859-1'){
    $text = htmlentities($text, ENT_COMPAT, $charset, false);
    $arr_xml_special_char = array("&quot;","&amp;","&apos;","&lt;","&gt;");
    $arr_xml_special_char_regex = "(?";
    foreach($arr_xml_special_char as $key => $value){
        $arr_xml_special_char_regex .= "(?!$value)";
    }
    $arr_xml_special_char_regex .= ")";
    $pattern = "/$arr_xml_special_char_regex&([a-zA-Z0-9]+;)/";
    $replacement = '&amp;${1}';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
}

function function_html2text($html = null){
    $tags = array (
        0 => '~<h[123][^>]+>~si',
        1 => '~<h[456][^>]+>~si',
        2 => '~<table[^>]+>~si',
        3 => '~<tr[^>]+>~si',
        4 => '~<li[^>]+>~si',
        5 => '~<br[^>]+>~si',
        6 => '~<p[^>]+>~si',
        7 => '~<div[^>]+>~si',
    );
    $html = preg_replace($tags,"\n",$html);
    $html = preg_replace('~</t(d|h)>\s*<t(d|h)[^>]+>~si',' - ',$html);
    $html = preg_replace('~<[^>]+>~s','',$html);
    // reducing spaces
    $html = preg_replace('~ +~s',' ',$html);
    $html = preg_replace('~^\s+~m','',$html);
    $html = preg_replace('~\s+$~m','',$html);
    // reducing newlines
    $html = preg_replace('~\n+~s',"\n",$html);
    return $html;
}

$sql_products = "QUERY WHICH IS NOT RELEVANT";
$result_products = mysql_query($sql_products);

//create a dom document with encoding utf8 
$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

//create the root element of the xml tree
$xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("feed");
$xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);

//create a dom document with encoding utf8
$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

//create the root element of the xml tree
$xmlns = array('atom' => 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom','g' =>'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');
$xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['atom'], 'feed'));
$xmlRoot->setAttributeNS($xmlns['g'], 'g:dummy', ''); //add a dummy attribute to add the google namespace to the document element
$xmlRoot->removeAttribute('g:dummy'); //remove dummy attribute

//Standard things like title
$xmlRoot->appendChild($domtree->createElement('title', 'title'));
$link = $xmlRoot->appendChild($domtree->createElement('link'));
$link->setAttribute('rel', 'self');
$link->setAttribute('href', $global_websitenaam_include);
$xmlRoot->appendChild($domtree->createElement('updated', date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
$addAuthor = $xmlRoot->appendChild($domtree->createElement("author"));
    $addAuthor->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name', 'author name'));
$xmlRoot->appendChild($domtree->createElement('id', 'tag:website.com,'.date('Y-m-d')));

//Producten doorlopen
while($product = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_products)){
    //HERE ARE OTHER QUERIES AND DEFINING VARIABLES WHICH AREN'T RELEVANT TO THE CODE
    $product_content = function_xml_entities(substr_replace(str_replace('&nbsp;',' ', function_html2text($product['content'])), "", 5000));

    // create the products 
    $addProduct = $xmlRoot->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['atom'], "entry"));
    $addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['atom'], 'id', $product['id']));
    $addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['atom'], 'title', substr_replace($product['name'], "", 150)));
    $linkProd = $addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElement('link'));
        $linkProd->setAttribute('href', $global_websitenaam_include.'/'.rawurlencode($product['category_slug']).'/'.rawurlencode($product['slug']));
    $addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['g'], 'g:price', number_format($product_price, 2, ',', '.')));
    $addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['g'], 'g:condition', $condition_product));
    $addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['g'], 'g:brand', substr_replace($product['manufacturer_name'], "", 70)));
    $addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['g'], 'g:mpn', $product['typenumber']));
    $addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['g'], 'g:ean', $product['ean']));
    $addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['g'], 'g:image_link', $product_image));
    $addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['g'], 'g:product_type', 'Huis &amp; Tuin &gt; '.$parentcategory_name.$product['category_name']));
    $addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['g'], 'g:availability', $product_stock));
    $addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['g'], 'g:manufacturer', $product['supplier_name']));
    $addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['g'], 'g:weight', $product['weight']));
    $addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['g'], 'g:featured_product', $product_advertisement));
    $addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['g'], 'g:size', $product['size']));
    $addProductShipping = $addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElement("g:shipping"));
        $addProductShipping->appendChild($domtree->createElement('g:country', 'NL'));
        $addProductShipping->appendChild($domtree->createElement('g:service', 'Standaard'));
        $addProductShipping->appendChild($domtree->createElement('g:price', number_format($shipment_price, 2, ',', '.')));
    $addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['atom'], 'description', $product_content));

    //$addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createTextNode($product_content));
}

//get the xml printed
header("content-type: text/xml; charset: utf-8");
$domtree->formatOutput = true;
echo $domtree->saveXML();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character nodes nodes do not have a namespace. Here are two types of them. Text nodes, which encode the XML special chars and CDATA sections, which use a special syntax. Both can be used for the `atom:description` and `atom:summary`. The expected content (for the Atom Parser) depends on the `type` attribute.

Default is just `text`, `html` means that it expects a HTML fragment encoded as text, `xhtml` are child nodes in the XHTML namespace.

You should not use the content argument of `createElement()/createElementNS()` or set the $nodeValue property, except if your are sure here are no special characters in the value (empty string, integers, ...). They use a broken encoding. Create the character nodes using `DOMDocument::createTextNode()` or `DOMDocument::createCDATASection()`.

Here is a small example:

```
$xmlns = [
  'atom' => 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
];
$htmlFragment = '<div>Description HTML Fragment</div>';

$document = new DOMDocument();
$entry = $document->appendChild(
  $document->createElementNS($xmlns['atom'], 'entry')
);
$summary = $entry->appendChild(
  $document->createElementNS($xmlns['atom'], 'summary')
);
$summary->setAttribute('type', 'text');
$summary->appendChild(
  $document->createTextNode('Summary Text')
);
$description = $entry->appendChild(
  $document->createElementNS($xmlns['atom'], 'description')
);
$description->setAttribute('type', 'html');
$description->appendChild(
  $document->createCDATASection($htmlFragment)
);

$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <summary type="text">Summary Text</summary>
  <description type="html"><![CDATA[<div>Description HTML Fragment</div>]]></description>
</entry>
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! It helped me understand the domdocument structure a lot better.